# Is it possible to add a blazor component in the root index page?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

[I am referring to this index page (wwwroot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INXKb.png)

I am working with blazor wasm and I don't like the "Loading..." you get when you first pull up the application home page. So I am working in the index page to replace that with a spinner. This is simple enough if you just use html but I prefer to create a spinner blazor component which I would then reuse in the rest of the app. Is this possible?

i.e.

```
<app><MyLoadingComponent/></app>
```

I would understand if this is not possible due to the fact that at this point blazor has not loaded (as far as I know).

Comment: The point of the loading page is to have something light, maybe a small animated GIF at the most. Even if this would work, it would defeat the entire purpose of a loading page.

Comment: Well no it doesn't defeat the purpose because as you said and as I mentioned I am just trying to add a spinner gif that is centered and maybe some text. It's not heavy and there isn't any scripts. It's more or less 5 lines of code.

Comment: But, the amount of effort blazor does to render a component actually *does* defeat the purpose. You should have pure HTML/CSS between those tags.

Comment: I think I figured out a way to do this. I'll post it when I get a chance.

Comment: There are lot of templates for pure HTML and CSS spinners out there, maybe something like [this](https://loading.io/css/) helps you?

Comment: Tried to implement a dynamic HTML/CSS spinner between the `app` tags. Cannot get it to work, either my site loads to fast or at this point of the startup no dynamic elements are supported.

Comment: @FernandoG if you replace the name `Blazor` with `React#` you'll get your answer. The root page just the place where the root component, `App` is rendered. Because `App` is a component itself. That component can contain other containers, layouts, routers etc. State flows from the route down, just like React. So yes, you can include your own spinner in WASM *but* you could also include a spinner with JS

Comment: Even if you've written a loading component in blazor, it defeats the whole purpose of waiting because by the time the loading component started to render the app would be ready to start too so there is no waiting.

Comment: My thought for a work around was to inject an html file to the index page and other components but at this point it is better to maintain two files.

Comment: Not sure why people think the loading spinner is going to be a big download. OP has 5 lines of CSS, there is no JS, and it's not going to take any significant time longer than the default "loading..." text.  OP is asking for a way to reuse the component.

I don't think it's possible though. I have just duplicated the code. Now I use the component everywhere else and the raw html only in Index.html. It's not great but will almost never change so I'm not too worried about it long term.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot load a razor component in index.HTML. But you could change the boring loading.... message with a nice page.

But the best option would be to use server side pre-rendering. This will render your component on startup while the rest of the app loads.